# Removing redirect in Grails Spring Security for Ajax

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

According to Doc: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/authentication.html for an Ajax Login, if the request is successful or fails there is a redirect.  I am not sure why this redirect is needed for the AJAX world and was wondering if it is possible to turn it off?  So that I just get back a success or fail to the Login POST request

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the method "authAjax" at the Login Controller so you can send a different HTTP status code instead of causing the redirect.

Take a look at the section "Securing AJAX requests" [here](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/).

Answer (score 0):

See the [AJAX Authentication](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/authentication.html#ajax) section of the Spring Security plugin docs.